Does the limit of the exponential mobius exponential series asymptotically equal its regularized power series?
Context:
Consider the function $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx}$. An extremely unrigorous manipulation of this series would yield
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(nx)^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^k $$
From here one might naively say via zeta function regularization:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx} = -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{12}x +\frac{1}{3!} \frac{1}{252}x^3 ... $$
And this statement is wrong! One must use the Euler Maclaurin formula (or assume the general form to be a laurent series) to correctly derive:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx} =\mathbf{-\frac{1}{x}}  -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{12}x +\frac{1}{3!} \frac{1}{252}x^3 ... $$
Notice that extra $-\frac{1}{x}$ term. Nevertheless, even if we didn't know about that term one can still experimentally see that if $A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{nx}$ and $B(x) =  -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{12}x +\frac{1}{3!} \frac{1}{252}x^3 ...$ that even though clearly $A(x) \ne B(x)$. It is the case that
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \left[ A(x) - B(x) \right] = 0 $$
Or at least:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \left[ \frac{A(x)}{B(x)} \right] = 1 $$
I'm interested in determining similar behavior for a more complicated series!
Question:
Consider the series given by $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)e^{nx}$ where $\mu(n)$ is the möbius function. This would normally be a very pathological thing to look at however I was inspired by this post which explores divergent renormalizations of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)n^k$. The poster observes that if $k$ is odd then it is natural to assign $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)n^k = \frac{1}{\zeta(-k)}$ (in the divergent regularization sense of the term). And if $k$ is even then experimental results (of averaging on the pole) suggest: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)n^k = \frac{\zeta''(-k)}{2\zeta'(-k)^2}$. Thus it becomes possible to write an incorrect resummation as:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)e^{nx} = -2 - 12x - \frac{1}{2!} \frac{\zeta''(-2)}{2\zeta'(-2)^2} x^2 + ... $$
Of course we do not expect this to be correct. There should be some weird singularity behavior ala Euler Maclaurin but the natural question then is if $A(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)e^{nx}$  and $B(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)n^k \right)x^k $ then is it possible that
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{A(x)}{B(x)} = 1 $$
My Explorations:
Experimentally, even if this is true, it becomes true very slowly: I created this desmos exploration and went out to the $24$th order and didn't see anything resembling convergence.
Now it is important to point out that $\frac{1}{k!} \frac{1}{\zeta(-k)}$ decays extremely rapidly for large $k$ along the lines of $\frac{1}{(k!)^2}$ AND based on some experimental tinkering $\frac{\zeta''(-k)}{2\zeta'(-k)^2}$ also seems to decay very rapidly. Even more so with that extra $\frac{1}{k!}$ in front. If these quantities can alternate signs frequently enough as they decay then it's definitely possible that this limit still holds! Unfortunately I think that requires a good deal more computer simulation or very clever analysis.

I was brought back here by your comment on my MO question. Thank you for bringing this to my attention again. I am thinking some line of Mellin inversion and Perron's formula, which is a similar idea for obtaining an explicit formula for $\sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda(n)$.
